# MacOS script to install tidyverse package after successfully installing R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a macOS script that installs R and it works fine. I want to add to the script to install the package tidyverse after R is done installing. I do not want to install tidy verse in the program R itself. Any help on how the scripting language needed so this can be done?

Comment: After `R` is installed, `Rscript` should be available as well. You can run `Rscript -e 'install.packages("tidyverse")'` from the command line.

Comment: Awesome @MrFlick! Thanks for that info! One minor adjustment though. I had to add a repo after the package name because it complained that there was not one. All is well now!